# Specify lvm filter in command?

Tags: filter, command, lvm

I exactly know the usage of filter in lvm.conf (from [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/lvm_filters.html)), but I want to specify the filters in command, like below:

```
lvs --filter [ "a/.*/" ]
```

The lvm just not support that, and I have try the `commandprofile` but it just not support section `devices`:

```
vgs --commandprofile test
Configuration section "devices" is not customizable by a profile.
Ignoring invalid command profile test.
Failed to apply command profile test.
```

So I want know is there anyway to specify lvm filter in command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the lvm command has the parameter `--config`,  use this parameter can specify the filter in command, like below:

```
lvdisplay --config 'devices{filter=["a|^/dev/sdj[0-9]*$|","r|.*|"]}'
```